# unzip (zip, tar, tag.gz) files with ruby

Tags: ruby, zip, gzip, tar, unzip

I want to unzip a lot of zip files. Is there a module or script that checks which format the zip file is and decompresses it?
This should work on Linux, I don't care about other OSs.

Comment: `tar cz` (usually producing `*.tgz` or `.tar.gz` files) use _gzip_ compression. `gzip` is incompatible with (and this question has nothing to do with) _zip_ / _unzip_.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To extract files from a .tar.gz file you can use the following methods from packages distributed with Ruby:

```
require 'rubygems/package'
require 'zlib'
tar_extract = Gem::Package::TarReader.new(Zlib::GzipReader.open('Path/To/myfile.tar.gz'))
tar_extract.rewind # The extract has to be rewinded after every iteration
tar_extract.each do |entry|
  puts entry.full_name
  puts entry.directory?
  puts entry.file?
  # puts entry.read
end
tar_extract.close
```

Each entry of type [Gem::Package::TarReader::Entry](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Package/TarReader/Entry.html) points to a file or directory within the .tar.gz file.

Similar code can be used (replace Reader with Writer) to write files to a .tar.gz file.

Comment: To expand on this great answer, you can extract files to disk with `Gem::Package.new("").extract_tar_gz(io, destination)`, where `io` is an object like `File.open("file.tar.gz", "rb")`

Comment: @AndrewKane worked perfectly, though passing '' to the package kinda weird. How does it suppose to work?

Answer (score 32):

The easiest way is to probably use Zlib

Zlib is a Ruby library. What follows is a simple program to grab a Zipped file from a particular URL, unzip it, and paste its contents to the screen.

```
require 'zlib' 
require 'open-uri'

uri = "www.somedomain.com/filename.gz"
source = open(uri)
gz = Zlib::GzipReader.new(source) 
result = gz.read
puts result
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Mavryx: When I am trying your snippet I am getting the following error:

unzip.rb:5: undefined local variable or method `uri' for #<Object:0x10018b298 @uri="http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz"> (NameError)

Comment: @maetthew check line 4 and make sure that you use same variable (uri here) in both lines

Answer (score 16):

Although [Florian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11505644/170230) is right, it does not take into account [tar LongLinks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2078778/170230) (Try extracting [jdk-7u40-linux-i586.tar.gz](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) from oracle :P ). The following code should be able to do this:

```
require 'rubygems/package'
require 'zlib'

TAR_LONGLINK = '././@LongLink'
tar_gz_archive = '/path/to/archive.tar.gz'
destination = '/where/extract/to'

Gem::Package::TarReader.new( Zlib::GzipReader.open tar_gz_archive ) do |tar|
  dest = nil
  tar.each do |entry|
    if entry.full_name == TAR_LONGLINK
      dest = File.join destination, entry.read.strip
      next
    end
    dest ||= File.join destination, entry.full_name
    if entry.directory?
      File.delete dest if File.file? dest
      FileUtils.mkdir_p dest, :mode => entry.header.mode, :verbose => false
    elsif entry.file?
      FileUtils.rm_rf dest if File.directory? dest
      File.open dest, "wb" do |f|
        f.print entry.read
      end
      FileUtils.chmod entry.header.mode, dest, :verbose => false
    elsif entry.header.typeflag == '2' #Symlink!
      File.symlink entry.header.linkname, dest
    end
    dest = nil
  end
end
```

Comment: is `:verbose => false` necessary?

Comment: No, I just didn't want anything to be printed in my use case.

Answer (score 2):

Draco, thx for you [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19139114). Some TARs encode directories as paths ending with '/' - see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28computing%29) Wiki. Examlple tar is [Oracle Server JRE 7u80 for Windows](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre7-downloads-1931105.html). This will work for them:

```
require 'fileutils'
require 'rubygems/package'
require 'zlib'

TAR_LONGLINK = '././@LongLink'

Gem::Package::TarReader.new( Zlib::GzipReader.open tar_gz_archive ) do |tar|
        dest = nil
        tar.each do |entry|
            if entry.full_name == TAR_LONGLINK
                dest = File.join destination, entry.read.strip
                next
            end
            dest ||= File.join destination, entry.full_name
            if entry.directory? || (entry.header.typeflag == '' && entry.full_name.end_with?('/'))
                File.delete dest if File.file? dest
                FileUtils.mkdir_p dest, :mode => entry.header.mode, :verbose => false
            elsif entry.file? || (entry.header.typeflag == '' && !entry.full_name.end_with?('/'))
                FileUtils.rm_rf dest if File.directory? dest
                File.open dest, "wb" do |f|
                    f.print entry.read
                end
                FileUtils.chmod entry.header.mode, dest, :verbose => false
            elsif entry.header.typeflag == '2' #Symlink!
                File.symlink entry.header.linkname, dest
            else
                puts "Unkown tar entry: #{entry.full_name} type: #{entry.header.typeflag}."
            end
            dest = nil
        end
    end
end
```