# Ruby / rubyzip alternative capable of handling rar/tar/zip/7z?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zip, 7zip, rar

I was wondering if anyone knows of rubyzip alternatives for Ruby, that can handle various formats in particular zip / rar / 7z?

I know of libarchive, but it's not complete for my purposes ( it's a good gem thou). <strike>(To clarify, libarchive - won't work for me - cause I need to be able to run in on Windows. ( Yeah I know sucks to be me))</strike> Libarchive actually works on Windows, but still not for my purpose (7zip & rar formats support)

Right now I end up running system commands to the os, but I'd like something OS independent, and capable of handling those formats - reading and writing.

Thank you

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856891/unzip-zip-tar-tag-gz-files-with-ruby

Comment: Joern, I just tried it, and it seems that it doesn't compile neither on ruby 1.8.7 nor 1.9.2 on Windows. I have devkit isntalled for both versions and other things like gbarcode, mysql2 or nokogiri - compile without a problem.

Comment: I stand correct - there is a mswin version of the gem that for some reason doesn' install by default - you need to force  to download the right version of the gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok for anyone else interesting as of now if you need more than rubyzip you can use libarchive, but if you need to support both Windows & *nix - your  best option is to go with a third-party binary. It seems that sending system commands to 7zip is easier. Also you can roll out a plugin and include binary static versions your favorite archiver. I'm going with 7zip since it's gnu and lgpl.

Answer (score 0):

Libarchive is available on windows:

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libarchive.htm

Are you sure Ruby doesn't work with it?

Comment: I haven't tried it for a while, but at the time I was referring to the libarchive gem, not the gnu library.