# Does File input support for compressed files in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-forwarder, logstash-logback-encoder

I'm trying to read files from compressed format files to parse it as input. Here are the file formats **gzip, zip,tar.gz**

I referred the two links but haven't get much information.

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/zlib/rdoc/Zlib/GzipReader.html

[Parsing a Zip file and extracting records from text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248791/parsing-a-zip-file-and-extracting-records-from-text-files)

I'm seeking for the example of how to writing codec to read the compressed files?
Is any other alternate solution to read compressed files?

Thanks
Deva

Comment: And your question is... how can I read compressed logs with Logstash?

Comment: Yes reading compressed logs with examples

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the code, logstash 1.4's file{} input does not handle gzip'ed files.  It looks like this is still true in 1.5.

Note that the s3{} input does handle gzip'ed files, so you could bring that code forward fairly easily.