# How to uncompress .tar.gz with Ruby on Windows?

Tags: ruby, windows, gzip, tar

I have a file `file.tar.gz`; how can I uncompress it with ruby to get the dir file?

on linux its easy to do this:

```
system("tar -xvzf file.tar.gz")
```

but is there any way to do this on windows with similar way or something else?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11505644/1520364 and other answers on that page

Comment: possible duplicate of [unzip (zip, tar, tag.gz) files with ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856891/unzip-zip-tar-tag-gz-files-with-ruby)